# JQuery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can I show Colorbox on page load without event binding? In a more simple term I would like the Colorbox to load immediately on page load.

this is the Colorbox which I am currently using http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `open:true` key/value set to the constructor if you want it to open without user interaction:

```
 $("selector").colorbox({ other_key:other_value, open: true});
```

However, it still binds to events if you were to close the box and try to reopen it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.fn.colorbox();
}
```

That is, if you make it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert('page loaded');
}
```

Then the alert will popup when the page has finished loading. So it's a matter of just replacing with the call that pops up the colorbox, which seems the one above (haven't tried though).