# Get Colorbox functionality without a popup?

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

I am using [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to present a series of HTML pages with `Next` and `Previous` buttons, with code similar to this:

```
<p><a class="myPages" href="page1.html">Page 1</a></p>
<p><a class="myPages" href="page2.html">Page 2</a></p>
<p><a class="myPages" href="page3.html">Page 3</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".myPages").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
</script>
```

It is working fine but in order start viewing the pages, the user must first click on one of the links.  This brings up a moadal window showing the content of the page they clicked, with `Next` and `Previous` buttons so they can switch to the other pages.

I would like to change it so that the content of `page1.html` is shown right away on the main page itself (not in a modal window), and the `Next` and `Previous` buttons are also shown.  In other words I want the contents of the modal window on the main page instead.   Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975170/jquery-colorbox

Comment: @Jakub, no... that will just open the popup automatically... I don't want the content to be in a popup at all... I want it to be on the main page

Comment: They are not popups they are modal windows, and still part of the 'main page' I think you are not explaining your question clearly enough

Comment: @Jakub... OK, I replaced all instances of "popup" with "modal window" in my question.  Now is it clear enough?

Comment: Seems like what you want is to AJAX load new content upon clicking Next/Previous. This is probably easier done without ColorBox.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Mior says, Probably not a situation for ColorBox. The plugin pretty much assumes you want overlay/popup/different window interaction.